# NetworkX: Check if two graphs have the same shape with same node attributes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

If I have two graphs with colour attributes:

[image: dags]
How can I check if both graphs have the same shape, with the same colours connecting to each other? The node number doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Graph Isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) which is available in NetworkX. You can check it out [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html).

Here is an official example from the documentation of `is_isomorphic`. You can view it [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic.html#networkx.algorithms.isomorphism.is_isomorphic).

```
import networkx.algorithms.isomorphism as iso
import netoworkx as nx

G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G2 = nx.DiGraph()
nx.add_path(G1, [1,2,3,4], weight=1)
nx.add_path(G2, [10,20,30,40], weight=2)

# This will be used for attribute matching
em = iso.numerical_edge_match('weight', 1)

print(nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2))  # no weights considered
#Output: True

print(nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match=em)) # match weights
# Output : False
```

Comment: Be aware that when the graphs get large, it may take a while to run this.  In this case, there are some faster algorithms that can sometimes definitely rule out isomorphism, but don't tell you for sure.  See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html for the various `could_be_isomorphic` algorithms.  They look at things like whether the degree distribution or the number of triangles is the same.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how does the edge match use the node attributes?